# Naming of clusters and labelling in TramineR

Tags: r, ggplot2, hierarchical-clustering, traminer

I am trying to do clustering of the following sequences. Unfortunately when I plot the clustering I am not able to find a way to label the states. 
For example instead of A, B, C,D, I want to label them as "Leopards", "Snakes", "Elephants", "Pandas" and I want to name the cluster 1, 2, 3 to "Group 1",  "Group 2", "Group 3". Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

```
 library(TraMineR)
 A<- c( 'A-A-A-A', 'A-B-C-D-A-A', 'A-B-D-A', 'A-B-C-D', 'A-B-A-A', 'A-A-A-A')
 B <- as.data.frame(A)
 actcal.seq <- seqdef(B)

 clust4 <- cutree(wardCluster, k = 3)
 seqdplot(actal.seq, group = clust4, border = NA)
```

Comment: Did you look at the user’s guide or at the vignette that comes with TraMineR? All this is explained there!

Comment: I did but I couldn’t find any information

Answer (score 0):

State labels are set with the `labels` argument of `seqdef`.

To get cluster labels, define a factor from your `clust4` variable.

I cannot show you because your code is not a working example.